# How to hide a class in a condition

Tags: php

I want to hide a class in a list tag from being displayed in an if statement.

In css:

```
li.Popup.EditAccountLink
```

so it should be something like this but ofcourse this is not the good syntax....

```
 if(!= Gdn::Session()->UserID) {
  li class Popup.EditAccountLink {
    "display:none;"

  }

}
```

Can someone help me make it the right way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'd do it like that:

```html
<?php

$class='';

if (condition) {
  $class=' class="hidden"';
} else {
  $class=' class="whatever"';
}

echo '<div'. $class .'></div>';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

(So that you have 2 different classes in css and if the condition is true you only have to change the `class attr.` of the `element`)

An example (Not valid code):

PHP:

```
<?php

    if(condition) {
        echo "<div class='normal'>TEST</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='hide'>TEST</div>";                                       
    }

?>
```

CSS:

```
.normal {
  display: inline;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

Hope you get the idea